# App crashes when tapped on two buttons simultaneously (save / cancel) what should be the severity & priority

Tags: testing

WHile performing a random test, i have tapped on both Save and Cancel buttons at a time present at the two corners of the ipad in a application. Now what should be the Priority and Severity for this particular sceanrio.

Note: The app crashes when tapped on both the buttons simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue of unintended concurrency.

I think the priority should be moderate or low as not many people are going to press both buttons simultaneously. So, there is a likelihood of someone doing accidentally yet not intentionally (except if they test the software).

The severity is different. It depends on the function of the application. Here are some examples:

1. have spend 10 hours on work and you loose it due to this bug (HIGH Severity)
2. app crashes, you started up again and everything is back to normal (severity low)
3. you have capture the one in the life time photo and... crash!
   (bloody high severity)

So, in summary, severity is how bad the damage is after the effect and priority is usually based on the likelihood of someone going down this scenario (perhaps stats of how many times people have done that will be another indicator here).